# PyQt continuously updating variable.

Tags: python, tkinter, pyqt4

I am very new to PyQt and new to GUI programming.  I am making a game.  I need a variable to update continuously (it is a function of the time).  I am struggling to figure out how to do this.  I did this in tkinter with self.after(10,self.updateCost()) which lead to an update every .01 seconds.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this in PYQT

```
QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(1000, self.updateCost())
```

Please add time according to your needs